# Sortable Not Working after Refresh Sortable Div

Tags: jquery, html, refresh, jquery-ui-sortable

I have 2 jQuery functions, one that allows for sorting and one that allows for deleting from divs from the list. Everything works fine until I delete one of the list items. Then dragging stops working until I refresh the page.

I was also having trouble that the delete function does not immediately delete the div clicked to be deleted, and if multiple are clicked, only the most recent will be deleted. This is why refresh the div in the delete function below.

Any help would be much appreciated!

JQuery Sortable

```
    $(document).ready(function(){   
          function slideout(){
      setTimeout(function(){
      $("#response").slideUp("slow", function () {
          });

    }, 2000);}

        $("#response").hide();
        $(function() {
        $("#list ul").sortable({ opacity: 0.8, cursor: 'move', update: function() {

                var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&update=update'; 
                $.post("updateReadingList.php", order, function(theResponse){
                    $("#response").html(theResponse);
                    $("#response").slideDown('slow');
                    slideout();
                });                                                              
            }                                 
            });
        });

    });
```

JQuery Delete Function

```
    $(document).ready(function(){ $(function() {
        $( '#reading' ).on( 'click', 'a.deletefromrl', function(){
            $(this).closest('li').fadeOut('slow');
            var order = $('#list ul').sortable("serialize") + '&update=update' + '&id=' + $(this).attr('data-storyid'); 
            $.post("deletefromReadingList.php", order, function(theResponse){
                    $("#response").html(theResponse);
                }); 
                var auto_refresh = setInterval(
                    function()
                    {
                        $('ul').load('reloadReadingList.php');
                    }, 0);  
        })
    })
    })
```

Comment: When you reload the list in the delete function you should probably consider rebinding the sortable list. That should make it work.

Comment: How would I do that? I'm sorry I'm very new to JQuery. Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1):

One solution would be to put the binding action in a function of it's own and call it on page load and then everytime you reload your list:

**EDITED:**
I'm not sure what was wrong in the last one, but this seems to work for me:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   
  function slideout(){
      setTimeout(function(){
      $("#response").slideUp("slow", function () {
          });

    }, 2000);}

    function bindSortable()
    {
        $("#list ul").sortable(
        { 
            opacity: 0.8, 
            cursor: 'move', 
            update: function() {

                var order = $(this).sortable("serialize") + '&update=update'; 
                $.post("updateReadingList.php", order, function(theResponse){
                    $("#response").html(theResponse);
                    $("#response").slideDown('slow');
                    slideout();
                });                                                              
            }                                 
        });
    }

    bindSortable();

    $( '#reading' ).on( 'click', 'a.deletefromrl', function(){
        $(this).closest('li').fadeOut('slow');
        var order = $('#list ul').sortable("serialize") + '&update=update' + '&id=' + $(this).attr('data-storyid'); 
        $.post("deletefromReadingList.php", order, function(theResponse){
                $("#response").html(theResponse);
            }); 
            var auto_refresh = setInterval(
                function()
                {
                    $('ul').load('reloadReadingList.php', function()
                    {
                        bindSortable();
                    });
                }, 0);  
    })
});
```

Comment: This didn't work, it disabled the drag and drop and other functions for some reason.

Comment: I've edited the solution, the new one works for me. Have you tried debugging it in [FireBug](http://www.firebug.com/)?

Comment: I'm trying now, but I really don't know what I'm doing or what's happening. Here is the site I'm working on: www.cgrtutoring.com/index7.php has my code and www.cgrtutoring.com/index9.php has the code above.

but when i debug index7.php it just says log maxed out GET reload script and then it shows line 2 where the query ui is, but I don't know what that means